# What is wrong in my $f'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We have $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}$ and we need to find $f'(x)$.

Here is all my steps:

$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=\frac{(2x-1)(x^2+x+1)-(x^2-x+1)(2x+1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}\\&=\frac{(2x-1)(x^2+1)-(2x+1)(x^2+1)}{(\cdots)^2}\\&=\frac{(x^2+1)(2x-1-2x-1)}{(\cdots)^2}\\&=\frac{2(1-x)(1+x)}{(\cdots)^2},\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\end{align}$$

> But in my book they say that $f'(x)=\frac{2(x-1)(x+1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$. What is wrong in my method ?

Comment: It's probably slightly faster to compute the derivative by writing $f(x)$ as $$1 - \frac{2x}{x^2 + x + 1}.$$

Comment: How did you get $f'(x)=\frac{(2x-1)(x^2+x+1)-(x^2-x+1)(2x+1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}=\frac{(2x-1)(x^2+1)-(2x+1)(x^2+1)}{(...)^2}$? The first step is the quotient rule, but how did you get the second expression?

Comment: You seem to have used the quotient rule correctly, but in simplifying the first lengthy rational expression it's not clear what your algebra is.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski $(2x-1)(x^2+x+1)=(2x-1)(x^2+1)+2x^2-x^2$

Comment: The last part should be $2x^2-x$, which does not cancel with $2x^2+x$ From the other part of numerator.

Comment: Check the second step

Comment: Oh, yes you've right @Macavity

Comment: $f'(x)=\frac{(2x-1)(x^2+x+1)-(x^2-x+1)(2x+1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}=\frac{(2x-1)(x^2+1)-(‌​2x+1)(x^2+1)-2x}{(...)^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the red parts in your "method".

$$(2x-1)(x^2+x+1)-(x^2-x+1)(2x+1)$$
$$=(2x-1)(x^2+1)+(2x-1)x-(x^2+1)(2x+1)+x(2x+1)$$
$$=(x^2+1)(2x-1-2x-1)\color{red}{+2x^2-x+2x^2+x}$$
$$=(x^2+1)(-2)\color{red}{+4x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You were quick in cancelling entire $ x ( 2 x -1) $ and $ x ( 2 x +1) $ . For the first term your logic is ok, not the next term. Else all fine.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
(2x-1)(x^2+x+1)-(x^2-x+1)(2x+1) & =(2x-1)(x^2+1)+2x^2-x-((2x+1)(x^2+1)-2x^2-x)\\
& = (x^2+1)(2x-1-2x-1)+2x^2-x+2x^2+x\\
& = -2(x^2+1)+4x^2
\end{align}$$